# WPF: binding based on column index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

In WPF,  how can I create a data trigger based on a `DataGrid` cell's column index?  I can get at the column,  but the column only has the `DisplayIndex` available,  not the real index. I need to style the cell in a way that includes the colum as one of multiple trigger conditions,  so I cannot just define a style for the column.

Comment: I'm curious if the column for a grid is a dependency property. If it is than I would bind to the element name of the grid that contains the column.

Comment: Here's a link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a2aaa61-0b8d-4f30-9f96-14c9b8a6a1c2/how-to-binding-a-property-to-datagrid-displayindex?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with adding columns of type DataGridTextColumn, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyDataGridTextColumn :DataGridTextColumn 
{
   public int ColumnIndex {get;private set;}

   public MyDataGridTextColumn (int columnIndex)
   {
       ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
   }
}
```

So by providing the column index (your value you need to find later) at the point in time of constructing the column, you can then access that when you are styling the column.